# Return rows of data frame that meet multiple criteria in R (panel data random sample)

Tags: r, panel, dataframe, sample

I am hoping to create a random sample from panel data based on the unique id.

For instance if you start with:

```
e = data.frame(id=c(1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,4), data=c(23,34,45,1,23,45,6,2,9,39,21,1))
```

And you want a random sample of 2 unique ids:

```
out = data.frame(id=c(1,1,1,3,3,3), data=c(23,34,45,45,6,2))
```

Although sample gives me random unique ids

```
sample( e$id ,2)    # give c(1,3)
```

I can't figure out how to use logical calls to return all the desired data.
I have tried a number of things including:

```
e[ e$id == sample( e$id ,2) ]   # only returns 1/2 the data
```

Any ideas???  Its killing me.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not entirely sure what your expected result should be, but does this work for what you're trying to do?

```
> e[e$id %in% sample(e$id, 2), ]
   id data
6   3   45
7   3    6
8   3    2
9   4    9
10  4   39
11  4   21
12  4    1
```

Or maybe you want this:

```
> e[e$id %in% sample(unique(e$id), 2), ]
   id data
1   1   23
2   1   34
3   1   45
9   4    9
10  4   39
11  4   21
12  4    1
```

Comment: If it's great, then it's courtesy in SO to check it.

Comment: @DWin, the problem must have gotten him (see his last line in the question). :)